# What is Julia's equivalent ggplot code of R's?

Tags: ggplot2, julia

I would like to plot a sophisticated graph in Julia. The code below is in Julia's version using ggplot.

```
using CairoMakie, DataFrames, Effects, GLM, StatsModels, StableRNGs, RCall
@rlibrary ggplot2

rng = StableRNG(42)
growthdata = DataFrame(; age=[13:20; 13:20],
                       sex=repeat(["male", "female"], inner=8),
                       weight=[range(100, 155; length=8); range(100, 125; length=8)] .+ randn(rng, 16))

mod_uncentered = lm(@formula(weight ~ 1 + sex * age), growthdata)

refgrid = copy(growthdata)
filter!(refgrid) do row
    return mod(row.age, 2) == (row.sex == "male")
end
effects!(refgrid, mod_uncentered)

refgrid[!, :lower] = @. refgrid.weight - 1.96 * refgrid.err
refgrid[!, :upper] = @. refgrid.weight + 1.96 * refgrid.err

df= refgrid

ggplot(df, aes(x=:age, y=:weight, group = :sex, shape= :sex, linetype=:sex)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.15)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=:lower, ymax=:upper), fill="gray", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.15)) + 
  ylab("Weight")+ xlab("Age")+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

However, I would like to modify this graph a bit more. For example, I would like to change the scale of the y axis, the colors of the ribbon, add some error bars, and also change the text size of the legend and so on. Since I am new to Julia, I am not succeding in finding the equivalent language code for these modifications. Could someone help me translate this R code below of ggplot into Julia's language?

```
t1= filter(df, sex=="male") %>% slice_max(df$weight) 


ggplot(df, aes(age, weight, group = sex, shape= sex, linetype=sex,fill=sex, colour=sex)) + 
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.15)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.15)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),width = 0.1,
                linetype = "solid",position=position_dodge(width=0.15))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = sex, colour = sex), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_text(data = t1, aes(age, weight, label = round(weight, 1)), hjust = -0.25, size=7,show_guide  = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(70, 150), breaks = seq(80, 140, by = 20))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("orange", "blue")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c('dotted', 'dashed'))),
         linetype = "none")+
  xlab("Age")+ ylab("Average marginal effects") + ggtitle("Title") +
  theme( 
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="Black", size=28, face="bold", hjust = 0.9),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=16),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color="Black", size=28, face="bold"),
    legend.title = element_text(color = "Black", size = 13),
    legend.text = element_text(color = "Black", size = 16),
    legend.position="bottom",
    axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=11),
    strip.text = element_text(face= "bold", size=15)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Have you read the Plots [documentation/tutorials](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/) ? You can start composing your plot and then you can search or ask here the specific issues that you have..

Comment: [AlgebraOfGraphics](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/AlgebraOfGraphics.jl) is a ggplot-like declarative plotting API in Julia.  Plots.jl is a matplotlib-like imperative API.

Comment: @Antonello, yes i have looked to some of the plotting packages in Julia. But i would like to still use `ggplot` for the time being as it is a bit more flexible and efficient in my opinion

Comment: AlgebraOfGraphics tries to get there, but as a real ggplot fanboy, it doesn't satisfy me yet (and really lacks R's non-standard evaluation). So for now, I export results and do my plotting in R. (AoG is already pretty cool, though!)

Comment: I won't be much help because I don't use ggplot2, but can I just ask if both the Julia and R code posted run with no problems? If yes, then it might just a matter of finding the RCall equivalents of `geom_errorbar`, `scale_colour_manual`, etc in the R code. It would be surprising to me if `@rlibrary` figured out the `+` for plotting just fine but not plain function names.

Comment: Secondly, if finding RCall equivalents doesn't pan out for some reason, the next thing you could try is R code chunks in Julia or Julia code chunks in R. With RCall, you can put R code in your Julia script with RCall's R-strings `R"r.code.function(r.var1, $(Julia_expression), r.var2)"` (R"""  """ for multiple-line R-strings).

Comment: Both codes run in R and Julia with no problem at all. I will try to follow your instructions, but since i am not fluent in Julia's language, i am not sure i will succeed. But thank you for the suggestions

Comment: One reason that some capabilities are not documented in Julia is because they just don't much apply (amazingly so in some cases).  For instance, the Measurements package lets me use values like 59.8 ± 5.0. And then when I plot those values, I get error bars in plots without any explicit action on my part. This doesn't appear as an entire section in the Plots documentation because it is an emergent property. The Plots package really doesn't know about this and thus can't document it. In ggplots, they *have* to document all such things because there isn't synergy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented before, you can use R-strings to run R code. To be clear, this isn't like your post's approach where you piece together many Julia objects that wrap many R objects, this is RCall converting a Julia Dataframe to an R dataframe then running your R code.

Running an R script may not seem very Julian, but code reuse is very Julian. Besides, you're still using an R library and active R session either way, and there might even be a slight performance benefit from reducing how often you make wrapper objects and switch between Julia and R.

```
## import libraries for Julia and R; still good to do at top

using CairoMakie, DataFrames, Effects, GLM, StatsModels, StableRNGs, RCall
R"""
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
"""

## your Julia code without the @rlibrary or ggplot lines

rng = StableRNG(42)
growthdata = DataFrame(; age=[13:20; 13:20],
                       sex=repeat(["male", "female"], inner=8),
                       weight=[range(100, 155; length=8); range(100, 125; length=8)] .+ randn(rng, 16))

mod_uncentered = lm(@formula(weight ~ 1 + sex * age), growthdata)

refgrid = copy(growthdata)
filter!(refgrid) do row
    return mod(row.age, 2) == (row.sex == "male")
end
effects!(refgrid, mod_uncentered)

refgrid[!, :lower] = @. refgrid.weight - 1.96 * refgrid.err
refgrid[!, :upper] = @. refgrid.weight + 1.96 * refgrid.err

df= refgrid

## convert Julia's df and run your R code in R-string
## - note that $df is interpolation of Julia's df into R-string,
##   not R's $ operator like in rdf$weight
## - call the R dataframe rdf because df is already an R function

R"""
rdf <- $df
t1= filter(rdf, sex=="male") %>% slice_max(rdf$weight) 

ggplot(rdf, aes(age, weight, group = sex, shape= sex, linetype=sex,fill=sex, colour=sex)) + 
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.15)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.15)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),width = 0.1,
                linetype = "solid",position=position_dodge(width=0.15))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = sex, colour = sex), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_text(data = t1, aes(age, weight, label = round(weight, 1)), hjust = -0.25, size=7,show_guide  = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(70, 150), breaks = seq(80, 140, by = 20))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("orange", "blue")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c('dotted', 'dashed'))),
         linetype = "none")+
  xlab("Age")+ ylab("Average marginal effects") + ggtitle("Title") +
  theme( 
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="Black", size=28, face="bold", hjust = 0.9),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=16),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color="Black", size=28, face="bold"),
    legend.title = element_text(color = "Black", size = 13),
    legend.text = element_text(color = "Black", size = 16),
    legend.position="bottom",
    axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=11),
    strip.text = element_text(face= "bold", size=15)
  ) 
"""
```

The result is the same as your post's R code:
[image: OP's R code in RCall's R string results in this plot]

Answer (score 3):

I used Vega-Lite (https://github.com/queryverse/VegaLite.jl) which is also grounded in the "Grammar of Graphics", and LinearRegression (https://github.com/ericqu/LinearRegression.jl) which provides similar features as GLM, although I think it is possible to get comparable results with the other plotting and linear regression packages. Nevertheless, I hope that this gives you a starting point.

```
using LinearRegression: Distributions, DataFrames, CategoricalArrays
using DataFrames, StatsModels, LinearRegression
using VegaLite

growthdata = DataFrame(; age=[13:20; 13:20],
                       sex=categorical(repeat(["male", "female"], inner=8), compress=true),
                       weight=[range(100, 155; length=8); range(100, 125; length=8)] .+ randn(16))

lm = regress(@formula(weight ~ 1 + sex * age), growthdata)

results = predict_in_sample(lm, growthdata, req_stats="all")

fp = select(results, [:age, :weight, :sex, :uclp, :lclp, :predicted]) |> @vlplot() +
@vlplot(
    mark = :errorband, color = :sex,
    y = { field = :uclp, type = :quantitative, title="Average marginal effects"}, 
    y2 = { field = :lclp, type = :quantitative }, 
    x = {:age, type = :quantitative} ) + 
@vlplot(
    mark = :line, color = :sex,
    x = {:age, type = :quantitative},
    y = {:predicted, type = :quantitative}) +
@vlplot(
    :point, color=:sex ,
    x = {:age, type = :quantitative, axis = {grid = false}, scale = {zero = false}},
    y = {:weight, type = :quantitative, axis = {grid = false}, scale = {zero = false}},
    title = "Title", width = 400 , height = 400
)
```

which gives:

[image: output]

You can change the style of the elements by changing the "config" as indicated here (https://www.queryverse.org/VegaLite.jl/stable/gettingstarted/tutorial/#Config-1).

As the Julia Vega-Lite is a wrapper to Vega-Lite additional documentation can be found on the Vega-lite website (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/)